# How do I make sure files are downloading via an S3 VPC endpoint and not via the public internet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc

I am trying to download files from an S3 bucket using the below code.

Files are being downloaded correctly however they seem to be taking abnormally long e.g. a 356MB file takes approximately 9 minutes.

```cs
AmazonS3ClientBuilder builder = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard();

AmazonS3 s3Client = builder
        .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
        .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
        .build();

var fullObject = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));

saveFile(fullObject.getObjectContent(), new File(fileName));
```

While checking the headers of `fullObject.getObjectContent()`, it shows that the protocol is HTTP & the HTTP method is GET.

I have also tried executing a `wget` command on the EC2 instance but it throws a 403 forbidden error:

> Connecting to mybucket.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (mybucket.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com)... connected.
>
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
>
> 2022-01-11 13:43:18 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

**Is there a way where I can check to make sure the file(s) are getting downloaded via the S3 VPC endpoint or via the public internet?**

Comment: Is your bucket in the same region as the hosted EC2 instance? Is your EC2 instance in a private subnet with no internet access? Or in a public subnet? An easy way to check would be to cut off internet access to the subnet and if the S3 request still works, it means that it is going via the VPC endpoint.

Comment: `aws s3 ls --region eu-west-1` would also fail on an SSH'd EC2 instance with no internet access, unless the VPC endpoint is working (considering the VPC endpoint is for `eu-west-1` as VPC endpoints are regional)

Comment: Yes, the bucket I'm using is hosted in the same region as the EC2 instance in a private subnet both are in `eu-west-1` region. Also, `aws s3 ls --region eu-west-1` gives me a list of all the S3 hosted in that region, and if I try to list another region's S3 it throws the error `Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://s3.eu-east-1.amazonaws.com/"`.

Comment: Okay perfect - it is using the endpoint then especially as another region's S3 endpoint is not available. Whatever you're downloading on has issues then with internet speed.

Comment: The answer to your question is that you are using an S3 region endpoint - if there's any extra questions, I'd advise creating a new question please.